# Dialog-confirm Jquery Ui: Calling a VB or C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to call a VB method from dialog-confirm Jquery UI. The problem is that chrome shows a 500 error from server. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Client Side:

```
<script>

      function asyncServerCall(userid) {
          jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'WebForm2.aspx/GetData',
              type: "POST",
              data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  alert(data.d);
              }

          });
      }

      $(function () {
          $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
              resizable: false,
              height: 250,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                  "Delete all items": function () {

                      asyncServerCall("test");

                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  Cancel: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Server Side

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetData(userid As String) As String
        'You can do database operations here if required

        Return "my userid is" & userid.ToString()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you enable/add this attribute to your class?

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]